# How to access files with a specific name?

Tags: r, regex

I have large folder containing various files. I am interest in the files which are pdf's and whose name starts with the letter B(non case sensitive).

My goal is to extract these files and store them in a separate folder using R.

Could someone give me a hint on how to approach this? I have never used R in this way and don't really know where to begin.

See my related post:

- [copying specific files into a new folder in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63825844)

Comment: You mean move the files to a new directory?

Comment: `filestrings::move_files` may be of help: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/filesstrings/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I would try the next. Let's assume the path to your first folder (if it is called `folder0`) is
`C:\Documents\folder0` or `/home/user/folder0` and let's assume you want to move the files to `folder1`.

First save your paths (change the written path with the actual)

```r
path0 <- "C:\Documents\folder0"
# or
path0 <- "/home/user/folder0"
```

Do the same with the path to `folder1` and call it `path1`. Then:

```r
setwd(path0)
system(paste0("mv ",list.files(pattern = "^[Bb].*\\.pdf$")," path1"))
```

Actually, I believe this should work on Linux or OS X. In windows you may have to use `move` instead of `mv` and/or `paste(list.files(pattern = "^[Bb].*\\.pdf$"), collapse = ", ")` instead of `list.files(pattern = "^[Bb].*\\.pdf$")`.